# How to read partial array data in loop using php

Tags: php

I have following array.

```
Array (
    [group] => 2 
    [group_com] => 2764800 
    [group_dom] => 1423296000 
    [user0] => user2013 
    [login0] => 1394481064 
    [logoff0] => 1394481112 
    [duration0] => 45 
    [user1] => user2014 
    [login1] => 1394481064 
    [logoff1] => 1394481112 
    [duration1] => 320 
    [user2] => user2015 
    [login2] => 1394481064 
    [logoff2] => 394481112 
    [duration2] => 120 
)
```

`['group']`, `['group_com']`, `['group_dom']` keys are single keys in array and I am able to read `[group]` keys data using below code.

```
$group=$result['group'];
$loginstart=$result['group_com'];
$loginend_tip=$result['group_dom'];
```

But `[user0]`, `[user1]`, `[user2]` keys can be less or more in array. So how can I get all `[user]` keys' value using loop? Loop will be used only for `[user]` keys and not for `[group]` keys. Or there is another way to do it. Please provide some guidance.

Thank you,

Comment: You can make your life a lot easier if you restructure your array to itself contain a users array instead of having user1, user2 .. usern keys.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to loop through all your array and filter on your needs like so:

```
foreach($myArray as $key=>$value){
    if(substr($key,0,4)!=='user'){
        continue;
    }else{
        //Here you have keys that start with 'user' only
    }
}
```

Note that the `else{}` part is not needed as any code after the `if` will be executed only if the statement is false because of the continue, but it is way more readable like so.

If you will be required to do this kind of thing often, sometimes on group, some times on user, you could use a multidimensional array to ease your work.

In my opinion, you would be better off with an array looking like this:

```
Array (
    [group] => 2 
    [group_com] => 2764800 
    [group_dom] => 1423296000 
    [users] => array (
        array(
            [user]=>user2013
            [login]=>user2013 
            [logoff]=>user2013 
            [duration]=>user2013
        )
        array(
            [user] => user2014 
            [login] => 1394481064 
            [logoff] => 1394481112 
            [duration] => 320 
        )
    ) 
)
```

This way you can easily loop on $array['users'] to have the data you would like about each user, and not need to do hard gymnastics with the incremental of the string keys.

Comment: foreach is rotating loop for number of keys in array and it is not giving proper result. Please advise if I don't understand what you are saying exactly.

Comment: Yes, foreach rotates through all the keys in the array, the if statement then filters if the key starts with user as asked.

Answer (score 0):

Filter array keys to get an array of users:

```
$users = array_filter(array_keys($yourArray), function($key) {
    return substr($key,0,4)=="user";
});
$users = array_values($users);
var_dump($users);
```

Comment: It is good to note that this will make you loose all the data of the array... so you will have to play with 2 arrays, one for the users and one for the total.

Comment: @Salketer: What do you mean with "lose data"? `$users` do now contain a list of all users from the original array. Nothing is lost from the original array.

Comment: Hence why I said you would have 2 arrays to juggle instead of keeping just one.

Comment: Yes, it all comes down to how he is supposed to use the data. I provided a solution to get all users.

Answer (score -1):

If you do this

```
$group=$result['group'];
array_shift($result);
$loginstart=$result['group_com'];
array_shift($result);
$loginend_tip=$result['group_dom'];
array_shift($result);
```

Now in `$result` you'll have only user variables. You can loop on it every 4 and store it in another array

```
$users = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i+4) {
    $user = $result["user".$i];
    $login = $result["login".$i + 1];
    $logoff = $result["logoff".$i + 2];
    $duration = $result["duration".$i + 3];
    $users[] = array($user, $login, $logoff, $duration);
}
```

Comment: Lookout, using `array_shift` deletes the first element of an array. Doing this will work ONLY IF the array preserves the keys in this order, any change will break everything. Your solution could work using `unset($result['group'])`. Also, $result[0] does NOT exists, your for loop is completely broken.

Comment: You're right, I didn't pay attention on the loop. I'll edit the answer. As for the array_shift, the array is not supposed to change, so it could be a way to to what asked

Comment: creating code while HOPING that the rest stays the same is bad advice... We do not know how the array is constructed.